# elasticsearch: how to remove stop words instead of replacing them?

Tags: elasticsearch, full-text-search, stop-words

i want to get 2,3-shingles without stop words. yet, when i check how it works:

```
GET /my_index/_analyze?analyzer=my_shingle_analyzer
{
  "text" : "Sue ate the alligator"
}
```

i get tokens like `"sue at _"` and `"at _ allig"` but not `sue at allig`. how to make elastic completely removes `_`?

my index:

```
PUT /my_index
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,  
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "my_shingle_filter": {
                    "type":             "shingle",
                    "min_shingle_size": 2, 
                    "max_shingle_size": 3, 
                    "output_unigrams":  false   
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "my_shingle_analyzer": {
                    "type":             "custom",
                    "tokenizer":        "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "stop",
                        "porter_stem",
                        "my_shingle_filter" 
                    ]
                }}}}}

PUT /my_index/_mapping/my_type
{
    "my_type": {
        "properties": {
            "title": {
                "type": "string",
                "fields": {
                    "shingles": {
                        "type":     "string",
                        "analyzer": "my_shingle_analyzer"
                    }}}}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behavior of the [`shingle` token filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-shingle-tokenfilter.html) when tokens are missing in the stream, due to the presence of a `stop` token filter for instance.

All you have to do is

1. override the default `filler_token` setting in your shingle definition and
2. add a a `trim` token filter after your shingle filter

So:

```
{
    "settings": {
        "number_of_shards": 1,  
        "analysis": {
            "filter": {
                "my_shingle_filter": {
                    "type":             "shingle",
                    "min_shingle_size": 2, 
                    "max_shingle_size": 3, 
                    "output_unigrams":  false,
                    "filler_token": ""                 <-- add this  
                }
            },
            "analyzer": {
                "my_shingle_analyzer": {
                    "type":             "custom",
                    "tokenizer":        "standard",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase",
                        "stop",
                        "porter_stem",
                        "my_shingle_filter",
                        "trim"                        <-- add this
                    ]
                }}}}}
```

Comment: after this i see i have to increase n-grams size. but also i got tokens with two spaces like `"at  allig"`. will it be a problem? should i add some pattern replacement to remove multiple spaces?

Comment: True, `trim` only takes care of boundaries, you might definitely add some pattern replacement, indeed.

Comment: i still have to remove extra spaces. when i find time to do experiments and if it works, i'll add info and accept your answer

Comment: Were you able to try this out by the way?